# How to simply disable parts of Django app?

Tags: python, django

For example my Django app has some additional functionality for User (additional fields, view function etc.). How can I simply disable these additional parts without rewrite any code? "IF" tag in templates and views or some integrated solution exists?

Comment: Or you could just return a different view (in `views.py`) depending on the user rather than using template tags.

Comment: I would suggest use only those parts which you need and any other part won't affect your application performance utils its being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify particular view in urls.py for the part which u dont want to use so it will show the html page like "This functionality is disabled" or somthing like that...:)